# Running a Quantized UINT8 lstm model generates FlexTensor Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, nxp-microcontroller

**Facing Error On running lstm model**

```
ERROR: Fallback unsupported op 32 to TfLite 
Explicitly applied EXTERNAL delegate, and the model graph will be partially executed by the delegate w/ 13 delegate kernels. 
ERROR: Regular TensorFlow ops are not supported by this interpreter. Make sure you apply/link the Flex delegate before inference.
ERROR: Node number 5 (FlexTensorListFromTensor) failed to prepare.

ERROR: Failed to apply the default TensorFlow Lite delegate indexed at 0.
Failed to allocate tensors!
```

**For solution i found to compile tensorflow by enabling flex support.** 

Tried compiling the tensorflow using specific toolchain path.
But to activate support of FlexTensor what changes i need to do in cmakelist & build ? 
I know to enable flextensor using bazel [Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select#cc) searching how i can do the same using cmake..